# how to add a konva shape in two canvas？

Tags: javascript, canvas

In HMTL, if i have a konva Rect element. I want to add it on to two konva Layers on two Stages, but only the second stage has the Rect?

my code is as follows:

```
      var width = window.innerWidth;
      var height = window.innerHeight;

      var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width/2,
        height: height
      });
      var stage2 = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container2',
        width: width/2,
        height: height
      });

      var layer = new Konva.Layer();
      var layer2 = new Konva.Layer();

      var rect1 = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 20,
        y: 20,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'green',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
      });
      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(rect1);
      layer2.add(rect1);

      var rect2 = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 150,
        y: 40,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'red',
        shadowBlur: 10,
        cornerRadius: 10
      });
      layer.add(rect2);
      layer2.add(rect2);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);
      stage2.add(layer2);
```

I expect the stage and stage2 to both have the rect1 & rect2, but the actual output is only stage2 has the rect & rect2.

Answer (score 0):

Stage is at the topmost level in Konva elements hierarchy. It should be only be declared once. If you want to have multiple elements use different layers and add them to one single stage. And add different rects on different layers. By using different layers you can isolate the rects and manipulate them as you wish.

Comment: You don‘’t underetand my mean。 the stage and stage2 are in two canvas， they all the only one

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have two div，in each div i new a konva stage and a konva layer。now i new two rects， i want the two div both can show the two rects.Understand??

Comment: Try adding layers on stage first and then add rects to layers. And remember to call draw() method on stage as well in the end.

Comment: @wan I have the same problem.  How you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Any node in `Konva` can have only ONE parent.
You can't add a shape into different containers. If you do this:

```
layer1.add(rect);
layer2.add(rect);
```

Then the `rect` will be removed from `layer1` and added into `layer2`.

So you have to create a second rectangle. If you want to have the same properties, you can clone the node:

```
layer1.add(rect);

const rect2 = rect.clone();
layer2.add(rect2);
```